# AS3 incorrect Button dimensions

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, flash-cs4

I have a `MovieClip` created in Flash CS4 which so far only has two textfields and a button in it.

The buttons width and height are set to 60 and 22.
If I select everything in Flash it confirms that the width and height of the entire movieclip is 130 and 120.

The problem is when I try and get the size in AS it returns 170 and 200.
After a while I discovered that the problem disappears if I delete the button,
and the the width of movieclip always acts as if the buttons width and height are both 100.

Is this a known problem?
If so, are there any workarounds?

Answer (score 0):

might be something to do with 'button' position, just check it is not positioned out of the main movie clip. also its absolute x, y should be (0,0).